# Playing gif file in repeat mode using MediaElement

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, gif

I want to play gif recurrsivley  file using MediaElement. Is there any inbuild property like (repeat or any other) to play files non stop ?

I have played in repeat mode using following code.

```
// ...
objMediaPlayer.Source=new System.Uri("XXX.gif");
objMediaPlayer.LoadedBehavior= MediaState.Manual;
objMediaPlayer.MediaEnded+=new RoutedEventHandler(previewPlayer_MediaEnded);

void previewPlayer_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  objMediaPlayer.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
  objMediaPlayer.Play();
}
//...
```

It working for the video file but not for gif, i m missing some thing or i have to do some thing extra for giff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there is problem in MediaElement with gif playing.for further references
[Look here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/93d50a97-0d8d-4b18-992e-cd3200693337)